# Endpoints clashing in different route files expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cant seem to use the same endpoint in different route files.

index.js:

```
var users = require('./routes/users.js');
var orders = require('./routes/orders.js');


app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/orders', orders);
```

routes/users.js:

```
baseDep.router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json("This is the users route");
});
```

routes/orders.js

```
baseDep.router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json("This is the orders route");
});
```

`localhost:3000/orders -->  This is the users route`

`localhost:3000/users  -->  This is the users route`

The second one works as expected.

The first one seems to using the endpoint in the users route file.

Can someone help figure out what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the documentation for express app.use() method, it tells you that you need to use next() function in the middleware so that is can move on: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

For example:

```
baseDep.router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json("This is the users route");
    next();
});
```